# How to get recent month, year(i.e March2017) and previous month, year(i.e February2017) and month number in two diffrent columns in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

How to get recent month, year(i.e March2017) and previous month, year(i.e February2017) and month number in two diffrent  columns in sqlserver2013.

The output format should be like below

### Month&Date     |   Month No|

|February2017  |         2         |

|March2017     |         3         |

Comment: What code have you tried? That is crucial to asking a good question, and to getting a quick response (especially as most people have no sql in front of them, but tweaking yours is easy). http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried like below      :                                                                                  select format(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0, getdate())  ,0),'MMMMMyyyy')
union all
select format(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0, getdate())-1,0),'MMMMMyyyy').                                                                          but i am unable to get month number in  a adjecent column

Comment: Include that (formatted) in question and you'll get quicker response. Also look at CONCAT() (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm) and using `select XXX, month` with duplicatating the diff part or even nested subquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select *
 From (values (Format(GetDate(),'MMMMyyyy'),DatePart(MONTH,GetDate()))
             ,(Format(DateAdd(Month,-1,GetDate()),'MMMMyyyy'),DatePart(MONTH,DateAdd(Month,-1,GetDate())))
             ) D([Month&Date],[Month No])
```

Returns

```
Month&Date      Month No
March2017       3
February2017    2
```

Comment: @Sanjay Happy to help